# Simple Javascript if statement problem

Tags: javascript, syntax, weblogic

I'm sure the solution is glaringly obvious, but I've spent an hour faffing about so would really appreciate any help!

The following javascript is meant to make a div visiable and another div invisible if the variable loggedin="true":

```
/* Javascript */

function showArticle()
{
document.getElementById('full').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('summary').style.display = 'none';
}
var loggedin="true";
var owned="true";
if (loggedin="true")
{
document.write("Logged In");
}
if (owned="true")
{
    showArticle();
}
```

.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>

<div id="full" style="display:none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur.
<div>
```

Am I right in thinking the issue is with my calling of the showArticle function?

Comment: You *are* aware that anyone with minimal technical knowledge will be able to see the articlewithout being logged in?

Comment: If this is JavaScript why was this tagged [php], [mysql], [project-planning] and [specifications]...?

Comment: Victor, I am aware - this system is just a proof of concept / prototype that demonstrates functionality :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your code into a text file and tried it - and it had the problem.

I put the javascript in script tags above the html.

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
function showArticle()
{
document.getElementById('full').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('summary').style.display = 'none';
}
var loggedin="true";
var owned="true";
if (loggedin="true")
{
document.write("Logged In");
}
if (owned="true")
{
    showArticle();
}

</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>

<div id="full" style="display:none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur.
<div>


</body>
</html>
```

This fails because when the javascript runs the div tags have not been added to the DOM, so the getElementById returns null.  I found this by using debugging the javascript in Firebug / Firefox.

If I moved the javascript to after the html, it works - as the DOM is then loaded with those items.

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>

<div id="full" style="display:none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur.
<div>

<script>
function showArticle()
{
document.getElementById('full').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('summary').style.display = 'none';
}
var loggedin="true";
var owned="true";
if (loggedin="true")
{
document.write("Logged In");
}
if (owned="true")
{
    showArticle();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome Chris! That was indeed the trick. Makes sense in hindsight

Answer (score 8):

change `=` to `==` , look on this [article](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/comparison_operators.html) (javascript operator)

```
if (loggedin=="true")
.....
if (owned=="true")
```

Comment: Using '=' is interpreted as an assign statement and will assign the variable to a value inside the if clause and evaluate its value as a boolean.  If you assign to "true", the if will always run.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `if (a == b)` and not `if (a = b)` : the latter assigns the value of `b` to variable `a` (and then uses the value of `b` to determine whether to run the if condition, which in your example is always the case).

Answer (score 2):

```
function showArticle()
{
    document.getElementById('full').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('summary').style.display = 'none';
}
var loggedin = true;
var owned = true;
if (loggedin == true)
{
    alert("Logged In");
}
if (owned == true)
{
    showArticle();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Mattcha, but it's the if(owned == true) {showArticle ()}* that still doesn't seem to work. (i.e. if I put document.write instead it does that as expected, however the showArticle function doesn't work.)

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me (**UPD**):

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    function showArticle()
    {
        document.getElementById('full').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('summary').style.display = 'none';
    }

    var loggedin = true, owned = true;

    if (loggedin == true)
    {
        document.write("Logged In");
    }

    if (owned == true)
    {
        showArticle();
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="summary">moo</div>
<div id="full" style="display:none;">foo</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So, what was wrong?

- unclosed `<div>` (the second one)
- appropriation instead of comparsion (`=` instead of `==`)
- strings instead of booleans (`"true"` vs `true`)
- script had no type (you should always set it. it is just a standard: `<script type="text/javascript">`)
- scripts should be within `<head>` tag (it is also a standard)
- **you were trying to access objects when they were not loaded yet**

Answer (score 0):

instead of loggedin="true"                                                                                      write as loggedin =="true"

Answer (score 0):

its really novice to hide content with javascript. But if you want to do it anyways, I would recommend erasing the content.

use

```
document.getElementById('summary').innerHTML = '';
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('summary').style.display = 'none';
```